# Use javascript to set action in django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, post

In `django 1.10`, I need to pass parameters from one html template back to `view.py`, and finally render again the same view.

The problem is in setting `action` in the html to use javascript.

This is my html template:

```
<form method='POST' action='/res/{{link}}/{{page_id}}/{{email}}/'> 
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{email}}">
      <input type="image" type='submit' src={% static "assets/images/twitter_icon.png" %}>
</form>
```

`{{page_id}}` in `action` changes as the user interacts with the web page (using a drop-down selector). The following javascript would be able to catch this:

```
<script>
function post_redirect_link() {
    var page_id = document.getElementById("sel1").options.selectedIndex;
    return '/res/{{link}}/'+page_id+'/{{email}}/'  
}
</script>
```

And I tried to set `action` dynamically as:

```
<form method='POST' action='post_redirect_link()'> 
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{email}}">
      <input type="image" type='submit' src={% static "assets/images/twitter_icon.png" %}>
</form>
```

BUT instead, I get a redirect of the type `/res/correct_link/post_redirect_link()/correct_email`, where "post_redirect_link()" is taken as string rather than being the value returned by the js method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: try doing `<form action="javascript:;" onsubmit="myFunction(this)">` and in your function, you make a `post` call to whatever address you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following.

```
<form action="#" method='POST'>
  <script>
     function changeAction() {
         var page_id = document.getElementById("sel1").options.selectedIndex;
         var url = '/res/{{link}}/'+page_id+'/{{email}}/';
         document.forms[0].action = url;
     }
  </script>
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{email}}">
  <input type="image" type='submit' onmouseover="changeAction()" src={% static "assets/images/twitter_icon.png" %}>

</form>
```